# How to prefix a table name in a context in. Net core3 and ef core3？

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

How to prefix a table name in a context in. Net core3 and ef core3？
I read the file. I don't understand. Mayday!

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace ZoLone.Logics
{
    public class DataContext: DbContext
    {
        public DataContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
        {

        }

        //public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }

        public IEntityTypeConfiguration<DataContext> entityTypeConfiguration;
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [schema](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relational/default-schema):

`modelBuilder.HasDefaultSchema("School");`

This will prefix all your tables in this DBContext with `School.` prefix